# Flutter HTTP request with JSON data to a Firebase function

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I am currently trying to set up our Firestore database for a Flutter mobile app to take data from a Firebase function and store it into the database. Currently, we are trying to pass an HTTP request to our URI and attach some JSON data to it.

My function is as follows:

```
exports.testFunction = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var data = {
        name: request.body.name,
        age: request.body.age
    };

    var setDoc = db.collection('users').add(data);
    response.json({result: `User ${data.name} at age ${data.age} added.`});
    return;
});
```

Currently, the data can be retrieved when using a web browser and requesting from `https://us-central1-[project-name].cloudfunctions.net/testFunction?name=[string]&age=[int]`. This also works within our Flutter app, using the entire URL as a single argument with no body. However, when trying a cURL request from the command line:

`curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"name": "[string]", "age": [int]}' https://us-central1-[project-name].cloudfunctions.net/testFunction`

Hypothetically, the data should be in `request.body`, but I am getting an error saying the request could not be handled. What exactly is going wrong here?

Later, we want to implement this request in a Dart/Flutter app by attaching the JSON object to the body of the `http.post`. Is there a missing link in between this process that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the cloud functions log?

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm getting an error saying: `Request body is missing data. { name: 'FFFF', age: 21 }` (just some test data I put in). There's also another error saying `Invalid request IncomingMessage` which has just the basic HTTP request forms.

Comment: Ana takers? I have the same issue calling a firebase function using curl.

Comment: I am having a similar issue where the request body received is an empty object

Answer (score 0):

The error `Request body is missing data` means that the payload that's being sent in the request needs to be mapped inside `data`. It's mentioned here in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference#request_body) that the Request body should have a `data` field.

```
var data = {
   'data':{ 
      name: request.body.name,
      age: request.body.age
   }
}
```